# why is coffeescript adding function when extending Object?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, javascript-objects

I am trying to write a helper method to find the intersection of two hashes/Objects like this...

```
Object::intersect = (obj)->
  t = {}
  t[k] = @[k] for k of obj 
  t

x = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
w = { a: true, b: 3 }
x.intersect(w) #=> { a: 1, b: 2, intersect: [Function] }
```

the results are as I expected/wanted EXCEPT for the addition of 'intersect' key/value.

What am I missing here?

Comment: If `w = { a: true, b: 3, d: 4}`, then `d: undefined` appears in the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property is enumerable, that's why it appears in both objects when you iterate.

A solution would be this :

```
Object.defineProperty Object.prototype, 'intersect', value:(obj)->
  t = {}
  t[k] = @[k] for k of obj
  t
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/filur/1/edit) (compiled as JS)

But modifying objects you don't own, especially `Object` is terrible practice and can lead to many unexpected problems for other coders. Read [Maintainable JavaScript: Don’t modify objects you don’t own](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/).

Here it would be as easy and so much cleaner to simply define a function taking two objects as arguments...

Comment: I understand about not modifying objects you don't own. Our development group continues to debate it. Even so, I prefer syntax of a.intersect(b) over intersect(a,b). In support of your point about OYDO - if I had written it `intersect = (a,b)-> t={};(t[k] = a[k] for k of b);t` I never would have raised the question. sigh. Many thanks!

Comment: @Paul I hope you'll finally settle for not modifying the prototype of Object, Array, and so on. It feels smart at first but really isn't wise.

Comment: There are some browser compatibility issues with `defineProperty`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Comment: The `prototype=` `intersect` is both `enumerable` and `writeable` (using the `defineProperty` options).

Answer (score 1):

Adding the 'ownProperty' check removes this `intersect` property

```
Object::intersect= (obj) ->
  t = {}
  t[k] = @[k] for own k of obj
  t

coffee> x = {a:1, b:2, c:3}; w = {a:true, b:3}
{ a: true, b: 3 }
coffee> x.intersect(w)
{ a: 1, b: 2 }
```

---

If `w` has `keys` that are not in `x`, they will appear in the result with an `undefined` value.

A more robust function could be constructed from `underscore`

```
_ = require 'underscore'
_.pick(x, _.keys(w))
```

Comment: This fixes it here, but the problem of having an enumerable function on all objects will be present elsewhere.